# I'm trying to code a script that tells me when the mouse enters and leaves a ClickDetector in Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, mouseevent, mouselistener, roblox, onmouseover

**Here's the code.**

```
local detector = script.Parent.ClickDetector -- setting a click detector variable to save time
function mousein() -- mousein function
    print("Mouse has entered!") -- print "Mouse has entered!" in the output
end -- end of the function
function mouseout()-- mouseout function
    print("Mouse has left!") -- print "Mouse has left!" in the output
end -- end of the function
detector.MouseHoverEnter:Connect(mousein) -- run mousein when my mouse hovers over the clickdetector
detector.MouseHoverLeave:Connect(mouseout)-- run mouseout when my cursor leaves the clickdetector
```

**I labeled the code to make this easier to read.**
*Please put the working code in the answers!* 
 **This is my first question on StackOverflow. I am new to coding.**

Comment: Tbh I labeled too much xD

Comment: You forgot to describe the desired behavior, and how the current attempt does not do what you want.

Comment: the desired behavior was in the functions mousein() and mouseout()

Comment: and i tried calling the functions

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `ClickDetector` instance.

```lua
local detector = Instance.new("ClickDetector")
detector.Parent = thing --whatever object you want to detect mouse stuff on
detector.MaxActivationDistance = 10

function mousein()
    print("Mouse has entered!")
end
function mouseout()
    print("Mouse has left!")
end

detector.MouseHoverEnter:Connect(mousein)
detector.MouseHoverLeave:Connect(mouseout)
```

---

Or alternatively, as stated in the API documantion, In order for `script.Parent.ClickDetector` to work as expected, it must be placed in a `Script` or `LocalScript` whose parent is the `ClickDetector`

[APIREFERENCE > INPUT > CLICKDETECTOR > MouseHoverEnter](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/ClickDetector/MouseHoverEnter#mouse-hovering-on-and-off-of-a-clickdetector)